# Get table row text python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

This is the html

```
<table id="dataLstSubCat" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">
                        <a onclick="ShowHideProduct();" id="dataLstSubCat_LnkBtnSubCat_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dataLstSubCat$ctl00$LnkBtnSubCat','')">Primers</a>
                      </td><td style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">
                        <a onclick="ShowHideProduct();" id="dataLstSubCat_LnkBtnSubCat_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dataLstSubCat$ctl01$LnkBtnSubCat','')">Intermediates</a>
                      </td><td style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">
                        <a onclick="ShowHideProduct();" id="dataLstSubCat_LnkBtnSubCat_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dataLstSubCat$ctl02$LnkBtnSubCat','')">Finishes</a>
                      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Now I want to extract the table data(td) text 
like I want to extract the text

**[Primers,Intermediates,Finishes]**

This is what I have tried

```
new_text=driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//table[@id='dataLstSubCat']/tbody/tr"))
new_text.text
```

which gives o/p in string and not in list

```
Primers Intermediates Finishes
```

Is there any way by which it can be done.

Comment: would new_text.text.split(' ') solve the problem?

Comment: @Nathan in case if tr element will have spaces in text it wont work anymore

Comment: @Nathan , It would not solve the problem, because **space** would not be the criteria for splitting, for e.g consider the **Dry Primers**  is the single word , if i split it by space it would not solve the purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the table data **[Primers,Intermediates,Finishes]** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_text_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_text_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#dataLstSubCat>tbody>tr td>a")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_text_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_text_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='dataLstSubCat']/tbody/tr//td/a")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `find_elements_by_xpath` and then with `for loop` add it to the list like:

```
list = []
new_text=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//table[@id='dataLstSubCat']/tbody/tr/td"))
for text in new_text:
   list.append(text.text)
```

Comment: It is treating it as a single string ['Primers Intermediates Finishes'] and not as a separate list elements.

Comment: ah I see, probably you need to update xpath to use td elements of table "//table[@id='dataLstSubCat']/tbody/tr/td"